# WebXR/VR Canvas how to interact?

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, webvr, unity-webgl, webxr

I am working on a WebGL VR game. It's working fine, however I can not interact with canvas, I can only see it but can not click on it. I am using VR interaction toolkit, WebXR export packages. The canvas render mode is world space. I have Added the VRUI System in event system and also added Graphic raycaster and VR Canvas on my canvas that works with VR APK but is not working with WebGL.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, we have to make the project in 2022.3.10f1 or above and import "WebXR Input Profiles Loader" from open UMP to interact with Canvas

here's the complete documentation:

https://github.com/De-Panther/unity-webxr-export/blob/master/Documentation/Using-XR-Interaction-Toolkit.md